# most suitable Panel layouts

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

Which LayOut Manager is most suitable for my GUI?

I need to make the above GUI but I didn't know which layout I basically used the flow layout(easy) just to set up all my components first.

[image: Expected]

[image: mine]

Comment: I need to know the layout of the Components for selecting and the main(contentpane)

Comment: Stop thinking of 'which layout for GUI?' and start thinking 'which layout for a ***part*** of a GUI?'. It is rare that the view a user sees, will be composed using a single layout. E.G. That GUI seen in the first image uses at least 11 different panels. While some panels might use the same **type** of layout, it must be using a total of at least 11 layouts.

Comment: yes I did have several panels 13 to be exact they have a blue border(should have probably used a distinguishable one). But what should I possibly use for the last main panel (called  Components for selecting )

Comment: *"But what should I possibly use for the last main panel (called Components for selecting )"* That question (which should have a question mark) should be included in the main question. Please [edit] to add it. The "Components for Selecting" would be well suited to a `GridBagLayout` given it has four sections, but neither the cloumns nor rows are of the same size (which if they were, would suggest a `GridLayout`).

Comment: Break the design into small, easy to layout containers. See some examples of this technique : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511724/3992939),  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368681/3992939),   [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342131/3992939)