# Best way to format JFrame elements

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm wondering what the ideal way is to organize buttons, textfields, text, etc. In JFrame, because the way i'm doing it now takes up a lot of lines and I struggle with making a good layout. I'm currently using GridBagConstraints so a more specific question is how could I have a button between gridx 1 and 2 without a big gap. Here's the code I have.

```
    myGrid.gridy = 1;
    myGrid.gridx = 1;
    getContentPane().add(firstName, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridx = 2;
    getContentPane().add(firstNameField, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridy = 2;
    myGrid.gridx = 1;
    getContentPane().add(lastName, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridx = 2;
    getContentPane().add(lastNameField, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridy = 3;
    myGrid.gridx = 1;
    getContentPane().add(studentID, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridx = 2;
    getContentPane().add(studentIDField, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridx = 1;
    myGrid.gridy = 4;
    getContentPane().add(grade, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridx = 2;
    getContentPane().add(gradeField, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridx = 1;
    myGrid.gridy = 5;
    getContentPane().add(hours, myGrid);
    myGrid.gridx = 2;
    getContentPane().add(hoursField, myGrid);
```

Comment: A [mcve] would probably be more helpful. But, I tend to break the UI down into seperate areas of responsibility, use panels to contain components which are related to each other

Comment: The way I usually use GridBagLayout is by creating a method that does everything for me, for example: `public JPanel addComponent(int gridx, int, gridy, int gridheight, int gridwidth, GridBagConstraints gbc)`

Comment: A common strategy to solve complex computing tasks, is to break them into small, well defined manageable tasks. Divide and conquer.
This also applies to gui: break the design into small, easy to layout containers. You can see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511724/3992939)  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368681/3992939) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342131/3992939). For more help post mre as advised  and describe the desired layout.