# GUI: how to properly set layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

I'm having some issues with setting layouts. (Don't mind the sizes of the buttons, I just want to understand layouts properly).

Here is the window that I want to make:

[image: Picture of what I want to make]

Here is the window I tried:

[image: I tried]

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Grid extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JCheckBox c1;
    private JCheckBox c2;
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JPanel ButtonPanel1;
    private JPanel ButtonPanel2;
    private JPanel ButtonPanel3;
    private JPanel CheckPanel1;
    private JPanel CheckPanel2;
    private JPanel TextPanel1;
    private JPanel TextPanel2;
    private JPanel EastPanel;
    private JPanel CenterPanel;
    private JPanel WestPanel;
    private JLabel l1;
    private JLabel l2;

    public Grid()
    {
        //CheckBoxes
         c1 = new JCheckBox("Snap to Grid");
         c2 = new JCheckBox("Show Grid");

         CheckPanel1 = new JPanel();
         CheckPanel1.add(c1);

         CheckPanel2 = new JPanel();
         CheckPanel2.add(c2);
         WestPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
         WestPanel.add(c1);
         WestPanel.add(c2);
         add(WestPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);

          //I don't get how to arrange the labels aligned with the textfields. 

         //TextFields
         l1 = new JLabel("X:");
         t1 = new JTextField("8",3);
         l2 = new JLabel("Y:");
         t2 = new JTextField("8",3);

         TextPanel1 = new JPanel();
         TextPanel1.add(l1);
         TextPanel1.add(t1);

         TextPanel2 = new JPanel();
         TextPanel2.add(l2);
         TextPanel2.add(t2);

         CenterPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
         CenterPanel.add(l1);
         CenterPanel.add(l2);
         CenterPanel.add(t1);
         CenterPanel.add(t2);
         add(CenterPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER); 

         // Buttons
         b1 = new JButton("Ok");
         b2 = new JButton("Cancel");
         b3 = new JButton("Help");

         ButtonPanel1 = new JPanel();
         ButtonPanel1.add(b1);

         ButtonPanel2 = new JPanel();
         ButtonPanel2.add(b2);

         ButtonPanel3 = new JPanel();
         ButtonPanel3.add(b3);

         EastPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
         EastPanel.add(ButtonPanel1);
         EastPanel.add(ButtonPanel2);
         EastPanel.add(ButtonPanel3);

         add(EastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }
}

public class oottest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Grid app = new Grid();

        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setSize(300,150);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me understand how layout works?

I have been watching lots of videos and tried different layouts but still can't get it right. Tell me if I used the correct layout or if I should change it.

Comment: Have you tried a simple Google search or read any Java tutorials? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: To make your code easy to read, please follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply guys. Yes i tried many different sites and im sorry if i don't understand well the layout properly.

Comment: Thank you @c0der for the tips and help

Comment: Im sorry if my code is messy, will try my best to change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51340495/3992939) answer can give all the control you need for the left part. 
If you are willing to sacrifice some control for the sake of simplicity, you can get away with two `FlowLayout` panels inside a `GridLayout`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Grid extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField t1, t2;
    private JCheckBox c1, c2;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;
    private JPanel topPanel, bottomPanel;
    private JPanel eastPanel, centerPanel;
    private JLabel l1, l2;

    public Grid()
    {
         c1 = new JCheckBox("Snap to Grid");
         l1 = new JLabel("X:");
         t1 = new JTextField("8",3);

         topPanel = new JPanel();//uses flow layout by default
         topPanel.add(c1); topPanel.add(l1); topPanel.add(t1);

         c2 = new JCheckBox("Show Grid");
         l2 = new JLabel("Y:");
         t2 = new JTextField("8",3);

         bottomPanel = new JPanel();
         bottomPanel.add(c2);  bottomPanel.add(l2); bottomPanel.add(t2);

         centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
         centerPanel.add(topPanel);
         centerPanel.add(bottomPanel);
         add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

         b1 = new JButton("Ok");
         b2 = new JButton("Cancel");
         b3 = new JButton("Help");

         eastPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
         eastPanel.add(b1);
         eastPanel.add(b2);
         eastPanel.add(b3);
         add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Grid app = new Grid();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setSize(300,150);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

More examples of applying this strategy: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368681/3992939) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511724/3992939) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47117723/3992939)

Comment: Thank you for helping me and taking the time to make me understand, i really appreciate.

Comment: Wow you really made me understand that really clearly man! I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I love a good screenshot, and that is a very instructive (not just good, but indeed *excellent*) screenshot.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson I am trying to follow the [high standards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/3992939) you set (0:

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a single column `GridLayout` for the buttons on the right, a `GridBagLayout` for everything to the left of them. Put the panel with the buttons in the `LINE_END` of a `BorderLayout` and the rest in the `CENTER`.

Here is how it might look:

[image]

Adjust margins, layout padding, insets and empty border for required white space. (Batteries not included.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help