# How to layout? (JFrame, JPanel, etc.)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtxDr.png]

I'm *very* new to Java Swing and Java overall (my class just got finished on `Scanner` and basics). I was taught only Swing basics which is "What is a JFrame..etc" and I'm stuck on how to layout or position things. On the image is the layout I desired and could anyone help and teach me how to code it? `JFrame` with, 5 `JPanel` components?(4 columns and the order form below)

Additionally, when clicking the "CONFIRM" button, I would want a new window to popup. How would I be able to link multiple windows?

Comment: 1) *"Additionally,.."* Additional questions are best asked on additional Q&A threads. This helps people find answers later. 2) Start from the 'inside out'. Identify a layout that can work for a small section. Put those components in a panel that is then positioned in another layout in another panel. 3) I would say that a `GridBagLayout` would work well for the title / author / code / price section, but a `JTable` would probably be better. 4) Consider using a `TitledBorder` instead of the title at the top. 5) Show some effort towards achieving the goal. SO is not a help-desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common strategy to solve complex computing tasks, is to break them into small, well defined manageable tasks. Divide and conquer.
This also applies to gui: break the design into small, easy to layout containers. For example:

[image]

You can see four fairly simple and distinct containers, named `headerPane`, `listPane`, `inputPane` and `buttonsPane`. 
The `mainPane` just warps (contains) those four.
The `inputPane` area is divided into containers, to keep the layout simple.

The idea is to keep each container layout simple, easy to follow and change.
`headerPane` can be as simple as:

```
JPanel headerPane = new JPanel(); //uses flow layout by default
JLabel header = new JLabel("LUNA BOOKSTORE ORDER FORM", JLabel.CENTER);
headerPane.add(header);
```

`buttonsPane` can be as simple as:

```
JPanel buttonsPane = new JPanel(); //uses flow layout by default
buttonsPane.add(new JButton("CONFIRM"));
buttonsPane.add(new JButton("RESET"));
buttonsPane.add(new JButton("EXIT"));
```

---

More examples of applying this strategy: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368681/3992939) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342131/3992939) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368681/3992939)

Comment: hey, I owe you a big time. This was a really big help and I learned smoothly how layouts work because of your guide. You saved me from a failed subject. Thank you so much!!