# Can I add a Table inside of a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm very new at using JPanels/Tabs and so have run into a bunch of issues with my code.
I've created a table from SQL that I want to be able to be viewed inside of a tab.
So I have a class first of all that includes a login and then takes you to a window with three tabs:
public class UserInterface
{
UserInterface() {

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //create a frame
    frame.setTitle("Bet Worthiness"); //sets title of frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //system exit when user closes window
    frame.setResizable(false); //prevents user from resizing frame
    JTextField text = new JTextField(10); //creates a text box
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 243, 181)); //background colour

    //Create panels
    JPanel accountTab = new JPanel();
    JPanel bettingTab = new JPanel();
    JPanel leaderboardTab = new JPanel();

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane(); //Create the tab container
    tabs.setBounds(40, 20, 1400, 700); //Set tab container position


    //Account Details label
    JLabel accountLabel = new JLabel();
    accountLabel.setText("Account Details");
    accountLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
    accountTab.add(accountLabel);

    //Betting label
    JLabel bettingLabel = new JLabel();
    bettingLabel.setText("Place Bets");
    bettingLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
    bettingTab.add(bettingLabel);

    //Leaderboard label
    JLabel leaderboardLabel = new JLabel();
    leaderboardLabel.setText("Leaderboard");
    leaderboardLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
    leaderboardTab.add(leaderboardLabel);

    //Associate each panel with the corresponding tab
    tabs.add("Account", accountTab);
    tabs.add("Betting", bettingTab);
    tabs.add("Leaderboard", leaderboardTab);

    frame.add(tabs); //Add tabs to the frame
    frame.setSize(1500, 800);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

I have then created a table on SQL in a separate class that I want to be embedded in the 'leaderboard' tab:

```
  public class Leaderboard extends JFrame {

public void displayLeaderboard() {

    try
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bettingappdb";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "lucyb";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        String query = "SELECT * FROM users";

        Statement stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(query);

        String columns[] = { "Username", "Success Rate" };
        String data[][] = new String[20][3];

        int i = 0;
        while (res.next()) {
            String nom = res.getString("Username");
            int successRate = res.getInt("SuccessRate");
            data[i][0] = nom;
            data[i][1] = successRate + "";
            i++;
        }

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setShowGrid(true);
        table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);



        JFrame f = new JFrame("Leaderboard");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(pane);
        f.add(panel);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Is there any way to put this table within the tab? Thank you :)

Comment: You add the JScrollpane to the tabbed pane the same way you add a JPanel to the tabbed pane. So your second class needs access to the tabbed pane of the first class. Your second class should NOT extend JFrame only create an instance of your scroll pane and then add it to the tabbed pane. So basically you just need a method that create the component to be added to the tabbed pane.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your Code.

```
JPanel lbTab = new JPanel();
Leaderboard leaderboard = new Leaderboard();
lbTab.add(leaderboard);
```

the Leaderboard is now in your JTabbedPane. If you want to add the Leaderboard as well as the leaderboardLabel in one Tab i suggest something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html or [How to layout? (JFrame, JPanel, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480767/how-to-layout-jframe-jpanel-etc) for your first steps :) .

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it working using this :)